# coinbase api client.get_accounts() not returning all wallets

Tags: python, coinbase-api

Currently the coinbase api will not get my atom wallet. with other testing code i was able to see that it was return 94 wallets however none them are my atom wallet and the accounts data doesn't even seem like it has 94 elements.

Any ideas on how to get my atom wallet to show? i tried the client.get_accounts(limit=200) trick with no success.

```
#import coinbase api
from coinbase.wallet.client import Client

# Coinbase Credentials
api_key = 'xxx'
api_secret = 'xxx'

# create a coinbase client
cb_client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
cb_accounts = cb_client.get_accounts()

# coin setting
coin = 'ATOM'

#print accounts
print(cb_accounts)

#get coin balance
for i in cb_accounts['data']:
    if i['currency'] == coin:
        coin_balance = float(i['native_balance']['amount'])

#print coin balance
print(coin_balance)
```

Sample Data returned:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "allow_deposits": true,
      "allow_withdrawals": true,
      "balance": {
        "amount": "0.00000000",
        "currency": "FET"
      },
      "created_at": "xxx",
      "currency": "FET",
      "id": "xxx",
      "name": "FET Wallet",
      "native_balance": {
        "amount": "0.00",
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "primary": false,
      "resource": "account",
      "resource_path": "xxx",
      "type": "wallet",
      "updated_at": "xxx"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the better way is to use coinbase api pagination parameteres:

```
#iniliase next wallet id 
next = None
# this loop will run until the next_uri parameter is none ( it means that there is no other page to show)
while True:
   accounts = client.get_accounts(starting_after=next)
   next = accounts.pagination.next_starting_after
   print(accounts.data)
   if accounts.pagination.next_uri == None :
     print("end")
     break
```

IF you like your script print your wallets with none zero balance, try this:

```
#iniliase next wallet id 
next=None
# this loop wil run until next_uri parameter is none ( it means that there is no other page to show)
while True:
   accounts=client.get_accounts(starting_after=next)
   next=accounts.pagination.next_starting_after
   for wallet in accounts.data:
      if wallet['native_balance']['amount'] != '0.00':
         print(str(wallet['name']) + ' ' + str(wallet['native_balance']))
   if accounts.pagination.next_uri==None :
     print("end")
     break
```

Comment: sample output:CHZ Wallet USD 11.07
SOL Wallet USD 9
DOT Wallet USD 15
ADA Wallet USD 19
ATOM Wallet USD 5.18
XTZ Wallet USD 4.67
XLM Wallet USD 10.68
Cash (USD) USD 0.10
end

Answer (score 0):

The API no longer supports pagination arguments. Instead, one has to work with "has_next" and "cursor" keys in the output which is limited to 50 accounts. Try this code. It should work.

```
from pathlib import Path
from coinbase.rest import RESTClient
from json import dumps

client = RESTClient(api_key='your', api_secret='your')

def list_accounts(cursor=None):
    accounts = client.get_accounts(cursor=cursor)
    account_list = []
    for account in accounts['accounts']:
        id = account['uuid']
        name = account['name']
        balance = float(account['available_balance']['value'])
        if balance > 0:
            account_list.append({'id': id, 'name': name, 'balance':balance})
    return  account_list
    

def has_more(cursor=None):
    accounts = client.get_accounts(cursor=cursor)
    if accounts['has_next']:
        return True

def get_cursor(cursor=None):
    accounts = client.get_accounts(cursor=cursor)
    return accounts['cursor']


def get_accounts():
    active_accounts = []
    cursor = None
    should_proceed = has_more(cursor)
    while should_proceed:
        active_accounts += list_accounts(cursor)
        should_proceed = has_more(cursor)
        cursor = get_cursor(cursor)
        
    return (active_accounts)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    accounts = get_accounts()
    print(dumps(accounts, indent=2))
```

You can always substitute lambda functions for above.